# Reverting a Pull Request Description

Tags: git, azure-devops, pull-request, azure-devops-rest-api

Is there any way to revert the description of a pull request to its original version after changing it using REST API assuming that it had never been completed, and it is still in its "active" mode?

Comment: After a brief search, I can't find it and would lean towards no, it's not possible. The only history of a PR I can find is "iterations/" (updates) and "threads/" (comments). I feel like this is one of those things where the answer is probably no, but I don't think anyone can  write up an answer stating that unless they work for MS on the rest API, or have read the entire spec... ;)

Comment: I suppose that you could create a [feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest?)  to raise your concern with more developers

Comment: (I initially posted a link to github, which wasn't relvant, sorry for the misread) Azure DevOps has Audit Logs : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/audit/azure-devops-auditing?view=azure-devops , but I'm not sure about the list of actions that are logged here, and you may need to activate a setting in your repo to have them at all :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not get the original text history of pull request description or its title.

If you know what text it was, then you can use the following API call from [Azure DevOps PR Patch API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0):

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullrequests/{pullRequestId}?api-version=7.0
```

Modify **description** in the request parameters.

Moreover, if you simply want to do it from UI, then in the PR section, just click on the pencil under description section:
[edit description in UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8xgC.png)

Hope this helps :)